# after effects workflow for popup roulette numbers

Tags: workflow, adobe-after-effects

I'm using After Effects to create png sequences for roulette's winning numbers.

First I create a sample animation with effects and transforms (8 frames).

Next I create timeline with colored numbers from 0 to 36 (38 frames with zero and double zero).

I had to remap my second timeline with numbers to fit it in animation (38×8 = 304 frames, new digit every 8-th frame).

Now I want to apply cycle animation loop for each 8 frames.

How can I do this? Or maybe there is another way to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was `loop_out` that I needed.

Here was the answer: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/674399

Comment: Go ahead and mark as **Answered** if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean cycle as in it rotates like a roulette wheel:

create a null layer (and set it's center to the rotation point) and parent everything to that, then rotate the null a full 360 degrees (or 1 in the number preceding the rotation angle in the timeline attributes) every 8 seconds.

or cycle as in cycling over the loops:

create 8-frame loop compositions and put them into a 'final comp' and duplicate/loop them over and over.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have allready found and implemented loop_out.

Answer (score -2):

I always forget stuff like loop_out—I would highly recommend [Auto Express](http://aescripts.com/pt_autoexpress/)!